# Changing an app's authentication that uses Active Directory from NTLM to Okta, do I need to touch direct calls to AD that aren't authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, okta, ntlm

Fairly inexperienced Software Engineer and with authentication so please bare with me with I get certain details wrong and thank you in advance for any assistance.

I've been tasked with replacing NTLM on an ASP.NET framework mvc app with OpenID as the authentication method and Okta as the Identity Provider. Client is a large company and will continue using Active Directory to verify users requesting access through Okta.

Replacing the authentication is reasonably straightforward to me now. It'll be a website redirect to Okta and back. What I'm unsure about is whether I need to interface through Okta to get AD groups information (like verifying whether a user is in a group or retrieving a list of users from a group) or not.

Thanks again for any assistance. I'll try to be as active as possible as I need to understand this fairly quickly.

I have tried googling and asking ChatGPT, but have not found good answers or that have sunk in. I don't have many experienced with Okta or updating an older app with NTLM to non-microsoft authentication methods in my workplace.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.